# How do I correctly escape the double quotation mark when using string.split

Tags: vb.net, string

`Dim mystring as string = " myintref="567" Mynewref="345" "`

I would like to split mystring at each single quotation mark  so that I end up with;

```
myintref= 567

Mynewref= 345
```

Neither

```
Dim splitstring as string() = mystring.Split(""")
```

or

```
 Dim splitstring as string() = mystring.Split(New Char {"""c})
```

appear to work.  Any suggestions?  (vs2015, vb.net v14)

Comment: I think VB escapes double-quotes in string literals by using two consecutive double-quotes.  Something like: `"this is a ""quoted"" string"`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but not quite what I'd intended (I couldn't get the question to format properly) myintref= should be one split, 567 the next etc.

Comment: @David  if you mean something like mystring.split(""""") then I've tried that and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Is the string you are trying to split this:  myintref="567" Mynewref="345"

Comment: If Your string value will be strictly, for example `Dim myString As String = "mysomething=""value"" mysome2=""value"" mysome3=""value"" mysome4=""value"""` then use space char for splitting (`.Split(" ")`) and remove double quotes (`.Replace(chr(34),"")`). But, if string format will be strictly like in this example.

Comment: @dbasnett  yes you've got that right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting 2 or 4 elements after splitting that string?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strLine As String = " myintref=" & """" & "567" & """" & " Mynewref=" & """" & "345" & """" & " "
    Debug.WriteLine("Original: " & strLine)
    Dim strAry As String() = strLine.Split({""""c})
    For i As Int32 = 0 To strAry.Length - 1
        Debug.WriteLine(strAry(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

Gives me this output:

```
Original:  myintref="567" Mynewref="345" 
 myintref=
567
 Mynewref=
345
```

Comment: @DomSinclair that's the exact same solution as David

Comment: @DomSinclair: Out of curiosity, how is the result of this answer different from the result of my answer?  The code in this one has considerably more cruft, but the result is the same.  We're both using `String.Split()` and getting the same exact resulting array.

Comment: @David  You're absolutely correct and I owe you an apology. and I have marked up your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

To escape double-quotes in VB, simply use two consecutive double-quote characters.  So you can do something like this:

```
Dim mystring As String = " myintref=""567"" Mynewref=""345"" "
Dim mystrings = mystring.Split(""""c)
```

Which results in splitting the string at the double-quote characters:

[image: Debugging screen shot]

Comment: Thanks David but you've misunderstood the question.  I want to end up with myintref= NOT "myintref="  and the same for the rest of them.  I want to use " as the split and that's what is causing the problem.

Comment: @DomSinclair: I think you're misunderstanding what strings are.  None of these split strings *contain* a double-quote character.  They're *enclosed* in double-quote characters because, well, *they're strings*.

Comment: @DomSinclair As suggested by David, the displayed output is right (you would be seeing the same quotes when splitting a string with no quotes, only define the start/end of the string elements). In any case, it seems that `Replace` is better for performing the actions you want.

Comment: @David your code is not exactly right. As far as with `Option Strict On` (-> informally assumed to be the basic standard of correction in the VB.NET posts of SO) it wouldn't compile. You are using the `Split` overload of one character by relying on a string. You should adequately define the character variable (i.e., `""""c`) or rely on a different overload (e.g., the one taking an array of strings: `Split(New String() {""""}, StringSplitOptions.None)`). For example, an exact convertion of this code to C# wouldn't compile in any case..

Comment: @varocarbas: Fair enough, answer updated.  I don't often have to use VB, clearly :)